# No text appears on TextView

Tags: android

This is my code, it should print a random value (between 0 and 1) but it doesn't do that!

I don't know how to fix it! I tried multiple things, none of them are working out!

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.lode.coder;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Coder extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView display;
    String one;
    boolean  bl= true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coder);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
    void all() {
        while (bl) {
           Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(2);
            one = n + (String) display.getText();
            display.setText(one);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling the all() method?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show where the `all()` method is called. If it's not called anywhere, that would explain why `display` never gets any text set.

But assuming that it is called somewhere, there's still a big problem: the `all()` method is an infinite loop. Until you return control to the framework, any changes you make to `display` won't show up on the screen. (In fact, your app will likely then be killed off by the framework when it notices that the app has become unresponsive.)

If you want to change the text continuously, look into using a `Handler`. You can create a `Runnable` that does the actual change and then reschedules itself to run again after a short time. Don't use a loop like you currently have in `all()`.

Something like this would work:

```
public class Coder extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 500; // every half second -- adjust as needed
    TextView display;
    String one;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable updater;
    Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coder);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        updater = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                int n = rand.nextInt(2);
                one = n + display.getText().toString();
                display.setText(one);
                handler.postDelayed(updater, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override protected void onStart() { // or override onResume() instead
        super.onStart();
        startUpdates();
    }
    @Override protected void onStop() { // or override onPause() instead
        super.onStop();
        stopUpdates();
    }
    void startUpdates() {
        handler.post(updater);
    }
    void stopUpdates() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't called all() function anywhere and even if you do, the logic would still be wrong because bl always stays true and so the while loop is an infinite loop which never stops. Try this code:

```
public class Coder extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView display;
    String one;
    boolean  bl= true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coder);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        all();
    }
    void all() {

            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(2);
            one = n + display.getText().toString();
            display.setText(one);

           }
}
```

if you want the loop you need to set your bl variable to false at some point to stop the loop from going on infinitely.

Comment: I think you meant `display.getText().toString()`?